# Why objectClass is different between LDAP servers

Tags: ldap

I am trying to write an application which sync users from multiple LDAP servers into one database. I was trying to write a code which finds all groups in the server from a given basedn. But then I noticed that objectClass values are different between LDAP servers.

Example, OpenLDAP uses objectClass=posixgroup to identify a group where as AD uses objectClass=group. Tried to find why isn't there a standard for this, but couldn't.

Is there a way to identify the value of objectClass name used by that server for groups other than configuring it for each server type?

Comment: Are you trying to use a common query for all vendor types?  If so, you can submit queries with attributes that do not exist.  For example:
`(|(objectClass=group)(objectClass=posixgroup))`

Comment: If I were to write an app for your functionality, I would define a query for each servertype and configure the different source servers accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLDAP does **not** use `objectClass=posixgroup` to identify a group. In fact, it is the services that connect to the directory server that use specific schemata or not. The directory server itself is oblivious (or at least it is from an LDAP standpoint -- Active Directory does more than LDAP).

On POSIX systems, e.g. Linux it is obvious that `posixgroup` is used by many services, likewise the `group` class is Windows-specific. Many services allow to customize how information is searched in the directory, i.e. you can adapt their configuration to your schema.

So while you can use tricks to work for both cases, if you want to really determine which schemata are used, you have two options:

1. Identify the services that are using the directory and look it up for them
2. Query the server for the schemata it supports. Often these are the ones that are also in use (at least by 'somebody'). For example on my OpenLDAP server I only included the schemata on a per-demand basis. So on this server you would find the `posixgroup` schema. However I doubt that on a typical Active Directory server you will find it (but you will find `group`). Schemata have world-unique Object IDs, so you can test for the presence of a specific ID to make sure `group` is really the `group` that you know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer to this. In the case of OpenLDAP and many others it depends what schema you're using. I use `groupOfUniqueNames` for groups and `organizationalRole` for roles in OpenLDAP, and there are other choices.